# Preferences menu item appears as "Settings"

Tags: macos, menu, menuitem

In the storyboard for my macOS application, I've included a "Preferences…" menu item that appears as the third menu item in my application menu (first item is my Amount, second is a separator, third is "Preferences…", fourth is another separator). Choosing this menu item brings up my preferences screen. However, when I run my application, this menu item always say "Settings…" and I'm not sure why or how to make it show what's defined in the storyboard.

Can someone explain why this is happening, or point me to the document that may provide an explanation and corrective actions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is something new to Ventura, as it reflects a change with the overhaul of System Settings with all apps now using "Settings" as opposed to "Preferences" when running under 13.x. When the app runs under earlier versions of the OS, the title assigned in the storyboard will still show up.

In any case, there is a way to change the menu item under Ventura, with the caveat that you should just allow the OS to manage this menu item for you in order to abide by proper human interface guidelines. The solution here is given just for completeness:

You can save the title (Preferences) assigned in your storyboard menu item title in the application's applicationWillFinishLaunching method, then reset the title in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).